# Qual a diferença de variáveis declaradas como final e private?

Tags: java, variáveis

Qual a diferença desses dois tipos de variáveis e por que elas não podem ser acessadas em determinadas partes do código? Eu li sobre métodos privados, públicos e abstratos, porém não entendi o uso do final.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Uma variável do tipo `final` só pode ser inicializada uma única vez, quer através de um inicializador ou através de uma atribuição.
2. Um variável do tipo `private` só pode ser modificada e acedida dentro da própria classe de uma forma directa. Para aceder e modificar uma variável deste tipo, fora da classe em questão, deve-se recorrer a `getters` e `setters` da variável.

Comment: Obrigado Urbester.