# Qual é a diferença entre o final, finally e finalize em Java?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, método, try-finally

Qual é a diferença entre os termos: `final`, `finally` e `finalize()`, na linguagem de programação **Java**?

Comment: Além: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27529/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38303/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/101 Pensei até em fechar por outros motivos, afinal comparações entre coisas que são cachorro, cachorro quente e sujeito cachorro não fazem muito sentido a não ser por linguística, a única coisa que essas três coisas tem um comum é que começam com *final*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`final`:

> `final` é usado para aplicar restrições na classe, método e variável. A
>   classe final não pode ser herdada, o método final não pode ser
>   substituído e o valor final da variável não pode ser alterado.

Exemplo:

```
class FinalExample{  
    public static void main(String[] args){  
        final int x=100;  
        x=200; //Compile Time Error  
    }
}
```

`finally`:

> `finally` é usado para colocar um código importante, ele será
>   executado se a exceção é tratada ou não.

```
class FinallyExample{  
    public static void main(String[] args){  
        try{  
            int x=300;  
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally{
            System.out.println("finally block is executed");
        }  
    }
}
```

`finalize`:

> `finalize` é usado para executar o processamento de limpeza antes que o
>   objeto seja coletado como lixo.

```
class FinalizeExample{  
    public void finalize(){
        System.out.println("finalize called");
    }  

    public static void main(String[] args){  
        FinalizeExample f1=new FinalizeExample();  
        FinalizeExample f2=new FinalizeExample();  
        f1=null;  
        f2=null;  
        System.gc();  
    }
}
```

[Material de Referência](https://www.javatpoint.com/difference-between-final-finally-and-finalize)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger você está certo, muito obrigado pela contribuição.